# ExtJs change maskRe of created input

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to change maskRe of created input field?
If yes, how?

```
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  maskRe: /\d{0,5}/i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, and you are already doing it.

BUT the maskRe is applied to the new character only. From the docs:

> An input mask regular expression that will be used to filter **keystrokes (character being typed)** that do not match. Note: **It does not filter characters already in the input.**

This means that maskRe cannot be used for a certain length requirement; you would use `maxLength` for that.

If you want to change it on the fly, there is no documented method to do so. In 6.0.1, as per the code, it should suffice to use `textbox.maskRe = newValue`, because the [`filterKeys` function](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/Text.html#Ext-form-field-Text-method-filterKeys) looks as follows:

```
filterKeys : function(e){
    /*
     * Current only FF will fire keypress events for special keys.
     * 
     * On European keyboards, the right alt key, Alt Gr, is used to type certain special characters.
     * JS detects a keypress of this as ctrlKey & altKey. As such, we check that alt isn't pressed
     * so we can still process these special characters.
     */
    if ((e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey) || e.isSpecialKey()) {
        return;
    }
    var charCode = String.fromCharCode(e.getCharCode());
    if (!this.maskRe.test(charCode)) {
        e.stopEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to change maskRe on fly. For example I change I have option "allow space character". By default it's false. So when I create input maskRe is "/[a-z]/i". When I enable the option I need to change regExp of input. But I cann't find where it's stored.

Comment: It's nice when ExtJs is up to date. I have 4.0.2 version, so it's doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Iva You haven't even tried and you have not tried to read the 4.0.2 ExtJS source. Can't help you with your laziness. It works in a [fiddle in 4.0.7](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/132t), and the source of filterKeys has not changed between 4.0.2 and 6.0.1.